# Disappearing answers

Tags: support, deleted-answers

I posted a question, [Restricting input to NSTextViewCell inside NSMatrix](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5888782/restricting-input-to-nstextviewcell-inside-nsmatrix), on stackoverflow yesterday afternoon. Last night, there was an answer and some accompanying discussion. This morning, it's gone - the question is still there, but not the answer.

Comment: Maybe it got downvoted and the OP removed it. That's usually the case with these things.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[He](https://stackoverflow.com/users/603977/josh-caswell) said,

> .... Sorry, I don't have any great ideas at
>   the moment, it's been a long day. I'll
>   try to look at this again tomorrow ...
>   In fact, I'm going to delete my answer
>   so that it won't show in the list.
>
> – Josh Caswell 6 hours ago

Answer (score 2):

The author said in a final comment "In fact, I'm going to delete my answer so that it won't show in the list." and then of course deleted their answer (at 5:41Z).

Answer (score 1):

The answer has been probably deleted from the user who wrote it.

The other explanation I could give, without seeing the answer, is that the answer has been flagged and then deleted, automatically or by a moderator.
To notice that some questions are automatically flagged by the Community user.